# Hey guys, I installed ROS jade instead of ROS indigo and I keep getting the following error while installing the rosdep. Someone knows what to do?

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
martin94@ubuntu:~$ sudo rosdep init
ERROR: default sources list file already exists:
    /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Please delete if you wish to re-initialize

martin94@ubuntu:~$ rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
Query rosdistro index https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml
Add distro "groovy"
Add distro "hydro"
Add distro "indigo"
Add distro "jade"
updated cache in /home/martin94/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache

martin94@ubuntu:~$ echo "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
martin94@ubuntu:~$ echo "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
martin94@ubuntu:~$ source ~/.bashrc
bash: /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

output of `ls -al /opt/ros`:

```
martin94@ubuntu:~$ ls -al /opt/ros
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 26 20:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 26 20:06 ..
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Aug 26 20:06 indigo
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216596/hey-guys,-i-installed-ros-jade-instead-of-ros-indigo-and-i-keep-getting-the-following-error-while-installing-the-rosdep.-someone-knows-what-to-do?/) by [martin94](https://answers.ros.org/users/23696/martin94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you need to edit your .bashrc file and remove the line that is trying to source the jade script - it looks like you do have indigo installed as you, but looks like you have also have added that line to your .bashrc file

In terminal in your home folder gedit .bashrc will open it, scroll down to the bottom and remove the line that sources the jade file, leave in the one for indigo. Save changes

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martin94](https://answers.ros.org/users/23696/martin94/) on 2015-08-27**:
It worked thanks!

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-08-28**:
thats great - please accept either of these answers as correct (click on the tick) to tidy up the forum

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> martin94@ubuntu:~$ sudo rosdep init
> ```

```
ERROR: default sources list file already exists:
    /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Please delete if you wish to re-initialize
```

This you can ignore (unless you want to re-initialize): you only need to run `sudo rosdep init` once, even if you (re)install a different version of ROS.

> ```
> martin94@ubuntu:~$ echo "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
>     martin94@ubuntu:~$ echo "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
> ```

If this is an actualy copy/paste, then again: you only need to do this once. The `>>` will cause `bash` to *append* the line you give to `echo` to the `.bashrc` file, so you'll now have multiple. That is not really an issue, just unnecessary.

> ```
> martin94@ubuntu:~$ source ~/.bashrc
> ```

```
bash: /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

Are you sure you have installed ROS Jade on this machine? This basically tells you that `bash` was unable to find `setup.bash` in the `/opt/ros/jade` directory. A successful installation of ROS Jade should have placed that file there.

Can you add the output of `ls -al /opt/ros` to your original question? Please use the *edit* button / link for that.

Also: please add on which OS you are doing this (ubuntu, yes, but which version?).

---

Edit: seems you edited your question title (old title: "Hey guys, I installed ROS jade instead of ROS indigo and I keep getting the following error while installing the rosdep. Someone knows what to do?"). My previous answer assumed you had Jade installed, *not* Indigo.

> output of ls -al /opt/ros:

> ```
> martin94@ubuntu:~$ ls -al /opt/ros
> ```

```
[..]
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Aug 26 20:06 indigo
```

From this (and from your updated question title), it seems you only have Indigo installed, but your `.bashrc` is still trying to read the `setup.bash` file under `/opt/ros/jade`. You don't have that, hence the error (the *No such file or directory* error, not the `rosdep` error, that is unrelated).

Open `.bashrc`, and look for a line `source /opt/ros/jade/..` at the end of it. Remove any lines that have `source` **and** `jade` in them.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-08-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1